# Create a Bookmarklet that clicks multiple buttons on one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, bookmarklet

I created a bookmarklet for a site a while back that ticks multiple checkboxes on a page:

`javascript:javascript:;$("input[name='unfollow[]']").attr({checked:true});`

Unfortunately the UI has changed and instead of checkboxes there are buttons that need to be clicked.  Here is an example of the HTML of one of the buttons:

`<button class="process mode-basic Unfollow" data-verb="unfollow">Unfollow</button>`

There can be up to 100 of these buttons. How do I create a bookmarklet that clicks all of these buttons? Is it possible to build up a delay between each click?

Thanks.

Comment: What site is this for?

Comment: It's called ManageFlitter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the page has jQuery loaded, you can click each one with a delay in between:

```
(function(){
    var unfollowButtons = $('button.Unfollow');
    var index = unfollowButtons.length-1;
    unfollow();

    function unfollow(){
        if(index >= 0){
            $(unfollowButtons[index--]).click();
            setTimeout(unfollow, 500);
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. I am writing up a blog post on this. Can I link to you anywhere and attribute this to you?

Comment: Glad it worked! If you want to link to me you can use Ben ([aldaviva.com](http://aldaviva.com)).

Answer (score 1):

```
$('button[data-verb="unfollow"]').on({
    click: function() {
        $('#result').append($(this).text() + ' was clicked<br/>');
    }
});

$('#unfollow-all').on({
    click: function() {
        $('button[data-verb="unfollow"]').each(function(index) {
            var el = $(this);
            setTimeout(function() {
                clickButton(el);
            }, 500 * index);
        });
    }
});

function clickButton(button) {
    button.click();
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6AJNc/1/

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately this doesn't work within a bookmarklet. Perhaps that the bookmarklet needs to be marked up as one function. Not sure.

Comment: if you move things around it does work :P accepted answer does the same thing, so I won't update mine

Comment: Thanks. I am sure it does, but I managed to get the other answer to work really well for me. I feel bad now! I'll vote your answer up because it was a very good one.

Comment: why would you feel bad? :) you got two solutions for your problem :P