# Create a bookmarklet that clicks multiple buttons on one page without jQuery

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

Last year I asked a question similar to the question I am asking here-

[Create a Bookmarklet that clicks multiple buttons on one page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18736339/create-a-bookmarklet-that-clicks-multiple-buttons-on-one-page)

The accepted answer works perfectly on a page that uses jQuery. However I need to get something similar working on a page that doesn't load jQuery. I tried to insert jQuery into the page in the bookmarklet but it refuses to load (the website doesn't allow it).

How do I convert the following to pure Javascript so that I can click multiple buttons on the page?

```
(function(){
    var UserFollowButton = $('button.UserFollowButton');
    var index = UserFollowButton.length-1;
    follow();

    function follow(){
        if(index >= 0){
            $(UserFollowButton[index--]).click();
            setTimeout(follow, 500);
        }
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of `UserFollowButton` equivalent to the query you just ran, you should use `getElementsByClassName("UserFollowButton")` which gives you an `HTMLCollection` of elements with a particular class name. Then, you can filter that collection to elements with the `tagName` equal to `BUTTON`.

Then, to click it, simply apply the method `DOMElement.click` to each element in the array. You can do that using `forEach`.

```
Array.prototype.slice.call( // convert HTMLCollection to Array
    document.getElementsByClassName("UserFollowButton")
 ).filter(function(element) {
     return element.tagName === "BUTTON";
}).forEach(function(element){
    element.click();
});
```

If you want the timeout, then you can simply set `UserFollowButton` to `Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("UserFollowButton")).filter(function(element) { return element.tagName === "BUTTON"; });`, then do what you are currently doing, using `UserFollowButton[i].click()` instead of implicit jQuery conversions.

Instead of having a global variable you are indexing from, though, try keeping the array local, passing it as an argument, using `pop` to take the first element, and keep passing it to subsequent callbacks.